# Find an open set such that the preimage of that set is not open given the function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
-2 & x<3\\
1 & x=3\\
3 & x>3
\end{cases}
$$ 
This is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence there must exist an open set for which the preimage of that set is not open. Find such a set.

I think that $(-2,2)$ will work, as the preimage "undoes" $g(x)$, so when using $(-2,2)$ an an input, the output will be $(-∞, 3]$. Which is not open.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Updated with my attempt

Comment: Notice that $-2\not\in(-2,2)$, but you're on the right track.

Comment: True! Brain is a little fried, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U =(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ be an open neighbourhood of $1 \in \mathbb{R}$ for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$.

We have $g^{-1}(U) = \{3\}$ which is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.